# How to pass datastructure in MVC post

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a form to update entity "Item", It has a drop down list for its category. So its model has two properties: string CategoryName, and List AvailableCategories. In my view, I will compose the combo box for user to select a category based on the value of both:

```
@if (Model != null && Model.AvailableCategories != null)
{
    List<SelectListItem> selectListItem = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var catName in Model.AvailableCategories)
    {
        selectListItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = catName, Value = catName, Selected = (catName == Model.CategoryName) });
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.CategoryName))
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("CategoryName", selectListItem, "Select Category")
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("CategoryName", selectListItem)
    }
}
```

So the drop down list is ready, and CategoryName will be updated when user submit. But the issue is the property List AvailableCategories is null when user submit the form. In my httppost controller code, If I need to perform some server side validation:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewItem(NewItemViewModel itemModel, string submit)
{
    if (contact server and find validation failed here)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("ItemName", "Server said it's not valid");
        return View(itemModel);
    }
}
```

Now the returned model "itemModel" has AvailableCategories set to null, since it's not present in the form. If I really needs to make this up on server side, I need to query database again to fill this list, which is not efficient. What is the most elegant way to compose this helper DataStructure back during submit?

What I can think of on client side is #1: Add a hidden field to save all strings so it can be post back, Or #2 Add submit function to compose all data into the model and then post from script. Then if there are server validation errors, I need to match those errors to the right validation field line by line...

Comment: Of course you need to re-populate the `AvailableCategories` on the POST method if you return the view. And what make you think it not efficient - its normal practice (its certainly a lot more efficient that generating hidden inputs for all properties of every `Category`.

Comment: And that loop does not belong in your view, it belongs in the controller, and in any case, delete the `Selected = (catName == Model.CategoryName)` code - that is pointless since its ignored by the `HtmlHelper` method when binding to a property. Or you could just use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryName, new SelectList(Model.AvailableCategories, "catName", "catName"), "Select Category")`

Comment: Hi Stephen: In order to re-populate AvailableCategories on the post method, I need to send a sql query to get the AvailableCategories again (unless I cache it life long). If I already know the categories didn't change, this operation just add an extra burden to the database. The worst case is someone keep submitting invalid forms to make the database very busy.

Comment: That's what a database is designed for :) And if you have correctly implemented client side validation, then its rare you would ever need to return the view. And if your database is correctly implemented, making a simple query to get that data is blindingly fast (better that creating all that extra html, sending it across the wire and sending it all back again unchanged). And you can always cache it (and invalidate the cache if `AvailableCategories` is changed